# Retrofit2 API request never returns. Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have an API service:

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new"

interface FooApiService {
  @GET
  suspend fun getInt():
    Call<Int>
}

object FooApi {
    val retrofitService : FooApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(FooApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

The server returns a normal HTTP200 text body response in the browser (I'm using a dummy API here). However I can't get it using the retrofit2 service (the function never returns):

```
private var job = Job()
private val fooScope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)

private fun doStuff() {
  fooScope.async {
    FooApi.retrofitService.getInt().execute()
    Log.i(TAG, "We never reach here! Why?")
  }
}
```

Why?

Comment: retrofit.create(FooApiService::class.java) how do you init retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont think you should use `suspend` with `Call`, because both of them are deferring
try changing to

```kotlin
interface FooApiService {
  @GET
  suspend fun getInt(): Int
}
```

Check if it works,

Edit:
Also, you should refer [docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), and check how to use `@Path` and `@Query`

```kotlin
private const val BASE_URL = "https://www.random.org/"
interface FooApiService {
    @GET("integers/")
    suspend fun getInt(
        @Query("num") num: Int,
        @Query("min") min: Int,
        @Query("max") max: Int,
        @Query("col") col: Int,
        @Query("base") base: Int,
        @Query("format") format: String,
        @Query("rnd") rnd: String,
    ): Int
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was generally correct (and I admit the contrived BASE_URL was faulty; you can't have query params otherwise it will cause an exception). Also, async doesn't rethrow exceptions, which is why everything just goes silent. Removing the Call fixed my code.